# Heroku redirects on acme-challenge despite ACM being disabled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I am attempting to setup Let's Encrypt free SSL on Heroku by following the steps here: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-heroku/blob/master/SSL-certificate-step-by-step-setup-instructions.md

I set the required file up locally and validated it by going to:

```
localhost:3000/.well-known/acme-challenge/<string>
```

The output looks fine, it is just a page with the required sting. I then push it up to Heroku, the deployment works. I then attempt to got to

```
http://www.<app-name>.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/<string>
```

and I am redirected to a web page that 
states:

```
This va-acm.heroku.com page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: https://va-acm.heroku.com/challenge?host=www.<app-name>.com&token=<string>
```

This should only happen if ACM is currently enabled, correct?

**Steps that I have taken to fix this:**

1. Disable ACM: `heroku certs:auto:disable --app <app-name>`. Ran fine, and now if I run it again states `Your app does not have ACM enabled`
2. I have tried spinning down the heroku app and have put it into maintenance mode.

I am using:

- A hobby dyno
- Rails version 5.2.3 & Ruby 2.5.3
- Godaddy

**My questions:**
How can I pass the acme-challenge? Do I have to disable something else on heroku to make this work?

Comment: That's a pretty old resource. Why are you trying to do this without ACM? That's the simplest and best option in my experience.

Comment: ACM does not support applications that have wildcard custom domains. Good catch on that resource being super old.

Comment: Also, I was using Let's Encrypt to get a free Cert

Comment: ACM is built on top of Let's Encrypt. You still get free certs. But if you need a wildcard I guess it's not a good fit.

Comment: I think it's impossible to do it. Heroku seems always redirect va-acm.heroku.com for the challenge url even disabled ACM. I've follow some old posts wrote in 2016 and face the same problem.

Comment: Hey! Did you find a way? I cannot migrate from ACM to custom SSL because of this.